# Reordering columns of a dataframe on the basis of column mean

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe

I have a data frame, which i want to reorder based on column mean. I want  to reorder it by decreasing column mean

```
    SNR      SignalIntensity  ID
1   1.0035798        6.817374 109
2  11.9438978       11.545993 110
4   3.2894878        9.780420 112
5   4.0170266        9.871984 113
6   1.6310523        9.078186 114
7   1.6405415        8.228931 116
8   1.6625413        8.043536 117
9   0.8489116        6.179346 118
10  7.5312260       10.558180 119
11  7.2832911       10.474533 120
12  0.5732577        4.157294 121
14  0.8149754        6.045174 124
```

I use the following code

```
means <- colMeans(df)  ## to get mean
df <- df[,order(means)] ## to reorder
```

to get the `mean` of columns and the `order`, but i get the column in increasing mean, opposite of my interest. what should i do to reorder in decreasing column mean

**expected output**

```
   ID SignalIntensity        SNR
1  109        6.817374  1.0035798
2  110       11.545993 11.9438978
4  112        9.780420  3.2894878
5  113        9.871984  4.0170266
6  114        9.078186  1.6310523
7  116        8.228931  1.6405415
8  117        8.043536  1.6625413
9  118        6.179346  0.8489116
10 119       10.558180  7.5312260
11 120       10.474533  7.2832911
12 121        4.157294  0.5732577
14 124        6.045174  0.8149754
```

Comment: I would suggest to take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296646/how-to-sort-a-dataframe-by-columns-in-r). The first Google hit on pretty much any "sort"/"order" and "r" variation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default settings in `order` is `decreasing=FALSE`.  We can change that to `TRUE`

```
df[order(means, decreasing=TRUE)]
```

Or get the `order` of negative values of 'means'

```
df[order(-means)]
```

Comment: @AaghazHussain  No problem.   You can check more details in `?order`

Comment: BTW, with the devel version of `data.table` you can now order data frames *by reference* without converting to a data table. Using something like `setcolorder(df, order(-means))`